# Why is this not on the same line?

Tags: html, css

i have the following code here that i am just playing around with. And the problem i currently have is that when i rezise my browser windows the table / section holding the text "mail @ mail com" is moved to the next row so it lays onto of the navbar. How can i make it not do this if someone resize their browser window?

```
<head>

    <title>some title</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<body>

<div id="header">
</div>

<div id="nav">

<a href="index.html"><img src="img/info.png" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:162px;height:50px"></a>
<a href="pris.html"><img src="img/pris.png" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:162px;height:50px"></a>
<a href="bokning.html"><img src="img/bokning.png" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:162px;height:50px"></a>
<a href="bat.html"><img src="img/bat.png" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:162px;height:50px"></a>
<a href="schema.html"><img src="img/schema.png" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:162px;height:50px"></a>
<a href="tavling.html"><img src="img/tavling.png" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:162px;height:50px"></a>
<a href="arrang.html"><img src="img/arrang.png" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:162px;height:50px"></a>
<a href="kontakt.html"><img src="img/kontakt.png" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:162px;height:50px"></a>

<a href="index.html"><img src="img/lamb.jpg" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:162px;height:162px"></a>

</head>

    </div>

<div id="section" width="100%">
<h1>KONTAKT</h1>
<p>
<div id="kontakt" align="center">

<font size="4">
questions? 
<br><br></font>
<font size="6">mail @ mail com
</font><br><br>

<img src="img/rockstar.png" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:350px;height:350px">


</p>
    </div>
        </div>

<div id="footer">
<br>
Copyright © you!!
</div>

</body>


#header {
    background-color:white;
    background-image: url("img/head.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;    
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
    height:130px;
    width:1450px;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;

}
#nav {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#white;
    height:300px;
    width:162px;
    float:left;
    padding:5px; 

}

#nav1 {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#white;
    height:10px;
    float:left;
    padding:5px; 
}

#nav2 {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#white;
    height:10px;
    float:left;
    padding:5px; 
}

#nav3 {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#white;
    height:10px;
    float:right;
    padding:5px; 
}


#section {
    background-color:white;
    background-image: url("img/bakgrund.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center; 
    width:1450px;
    float:left;
    padding:10px; 
    text-align:center;
    height:600px;


}

#innersection {
    line-height:20px;   
    width:650px;
    height:600px;
    float:center;
    padding:10px; 
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;
    text-align:left;    
}

#kontakt {
    line-height:20px;   
    width:650px;
    height:600px;
    float:center;
    padding:10px; 
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;
    text-align:center;  
}


#footer {
    h1   {color:white}  
    background-color:white;
    background-image: url("img/foot.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center; 
    color:white;
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px; 
    height:85px;
}
```

Comment: First off your ordering isn't even close to correct... You open the `<head>` and then `<body>` then close the `<head>`...  Plus you have your `<nav>` inside of `<head>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML needs a little help.      Also, you should avoid using font tags in your html.  You can control your font size in your css.  I'm assuming the CSS at the bottom of all of this is your external stylesheet you're linking to in your ? I somewhat cleaned your code up for you, but there's a lot more to take care of with the little things. For example   align="center" is outdated, and shouldn't be used.  If you're wanting to center text, use text-align: center in your css.

It's a start to at least get you on the right path!

```
<head>

    <title>some title</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div id="header">
</div>

<div id="nav">
<a href="index.html"><img src="img/info.png" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:162px;height:50px"></a>
<a href="pris.html"><img src="img/pris.png" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:162px;height:50px"></a>
<a href="bokning.html"><img src="img/bokning.png" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:162px;height:50px"></a>
<a href="bat.html"><img src="img/bat.png" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:162px;height:50px"></a>
<a href="schema.html"><img src="img/schema.png" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:162px;height:50px"></a>
<a href="tavling.html"><img src="img/tavling.png" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:162px;height:50px"></a>
<a href="arrang.html"><img src="img/arrang.png" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:162px;height:50px"></a>
<a href="kontakt.html"><img src="img/kontakt.png" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:162px;height:50px"></a>

<a href="index.html"><img src="img/lamb.jpg" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:162px;height:162px"></a>    
    </div>

<div id="section" width="100%">
<h1>KONTAKT</h1>
<p>
<div id="kontakt" align="center">

<font size="4">
questions? 
<br><br></font>
<font size="6">mail @ mail com
</font><br><br>

<img src="img/rockstar.png" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:350px;height:350px">


    </div>
        </div>

<div id="footer">
<br>
Copyright © you!!
</div>

</body>


#header {
    background-color:white;
    background-image: url("img/head.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;    
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
    height:130px;
    width:1450px;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;

}
#nav {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#white;
    height:300px;
    width:162px;
    float:left;
    padding:5px; 

}

#nav1 {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#white;
    height:10px;
    float:left;
    padding:5px; 
}

#nav2 {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#white;
    height:10px;
    float:left;
    padding:5px; 
}

#nav3 {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#white;
    height:10px;
    float:right;
    padding:5px; 
}


#section {
    background-color:white;
    background-image: url("img/bakgrund.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center; 
    width:1450px;
    float:left;
    padding:10px; 
    text-align:center;
    height:600px;


}

#innersection {
    line-height:20px;   
    width:650px;
    height:600px;
    float:center;
    padding:10px; 
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;
    text-align:left;    
}

#kontakt {
    line-height:20px;   
    width:650px;
    height:600px;
    float:center;
    padding:10px; 
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;
    text-align:center;  
}


#footer {
    h1   {color:white}  
    background-color:white;
    background-image: url("img/foot.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center; 
    color:white;
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px; 
    height:85px;
}
```